# Adding a stat_function layer to a geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a trajectory line representing brain atrophy over time. I have two specific trajectories for two different groups, and I want to add each of these two lines (for comparison) to a scatterplot of Age by Brain Volume.

The y-intercepts of these lines are 565 and 286, yet using the stat_function layer it seems to be placing the intercepts at very weird values, corrupting the overall scatterplot. Of course I can use ylim(), but then the functions don't appear (and they'd still be mis-specified even if they did).

My code:

```
ggplot(na.omit(GRAPHICSMATRIX), aes(x=Age, y=FrontalPole, colour=Dx_Bl)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +  
  ylim(0, 500) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) {-2.129*x^3 - 23.456*x + 565}, colour="blue", size=1) +  
  stat_function(fun=function(x) (286)+((-0.997)*(x)^3), colour="darkred", size=2)
```

Here are the graphs.

[image: Correct Scatterplot]

[image: Incorrect Scatterplot with two stat_function()]

Comment: Did you run `function(x) {-2.129*x^3 - 23.456*x + 565}` with `GRAPHICSMATRIX$Age` as input outside of the ggplot2 code?

Comment: The y-intercepts are reasonable numbers, but those are evaluated at `x=0`. Your plots start around `x=60` in which case you function gives a result on the order of 216,000. Just plug in `x=60` and you can see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your y-intercepts are `565` and `286` respectively, but those values are for when `x=0`. The plots you show in your question start at around `x=55`. In this case when we plug in `x=55` for your functions we get:

`-2.129(55^3) - 23.456(55) + 565 = 354,937.455`

`286 + -0.997*(55^3) = 165,589.875`

So what you're thinking is your y-intercept is not actually. I think you `stat_functions` are working correctly. If you don't like the results I think you need to re-think the functions you want to plot.

Comment: Thank you. My model was based on a demographic of 55-90 year olds, but the model calculations presume an intercept of 0. So I solved this issue by shifting the functions to the right by 55, which I did by subtracting 55 at each X (ie (x-55)^2)
Thank you!